# Regarding use of @Override annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, overriding

I am working on webservices with spring DI. I am using the Eclipse IDE and have written a validator. I am testing the code in SoapUI. The question is I have a validator class `UpdateRequestValidator` which is extending another interface `IValidator` which has a method `validate()` and therefore the `UpdateRequestValidator` class is implementing the `validate()` method. This method is being called from an endpoint adadpter class. I am using an annotation `@Override` before `validate()` method in `UpdateRequestValidator` class. The validator is working fine with or without the `@Override` annotation.

Now the question is that what role is this annotation playing here, and is there any side-effect if i remove it because the code and validator is working perfectly well after removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Override is just a "tag" telling the compiler that that metode overrides another methode.
Removing @Override would not change anything but if you remove the validate() methode in the parent class and still have the override notation you'll get a compile time error

Comment: Thanks nist...i understood it.